# exploration and exploitation in Q-learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

In Q-learning algorithm, the selection of an action depends on the current state and the values of the Q-matrix. I want to know if these Q-values are updated only during the exploration step or they change also in the exploitation step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the Q-learning algorithm code, for example from [Sutton & Barto book](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html):
[image]

It seems pretty clear that Q-values are always updated, independently if the chosen action is exploratory or not.

Notice that line "Choose *a* from *s* using policy derived from *Q* (e.g., epsilon-greedy)" means that the action some times will be exploratory.